# Set Parent Property From Children in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've created a status bar:

```
    <StatusBar>
        <StatusBarItem >
            <WrapPanel>
                <Image Source="/MyApp;component/Images/icon.png" />
                <TextBlock Name="_StatusbarUser" Text="Username"  />
            </WrapPanel>
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
```

How to create a trigger, when i set the textblock visibility to collapse,
it will also triger parent status bar visibility.

I've try using style bellow, but didn't work

```
   <StatusBar Grid.Row="2" Name="_Statusbar">
        <StatusBar.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type StatusBarItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TextBlock}}, Path=Visibility}" Value="Collapsed">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </StatusBar.Resources>
        <StatusBarItem>
            <WrapPanel>
                <Image  Source="/MyApp;component/Images/icon.png" />
                <TextBlock Name="_StatusbarUser" Text="Username" />
            </WrapPanel>
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
```

Help please, thx

Comment: I don't understand your code. You have a trigger that will fire when the Visibility of a TextBlock goes to collapse, which then also wants to set the visibility of the StatusbarItem to collapse. Also RelativeSource goes the tree upwards, but your TextBlock is a child of the StatusBar so this will not work. You can try to use TargetName but again, i don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks, it's solved by bind parent property to child property (from LPL). The idea is i want create a status bar with image, i want only access the textblock from my code, to set text content and it's visibility. But when i collapsing the texblock, the image still remain there. so i want to set the parent element (statusbaritem) to collapsed to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better bind parent property to child property:

```
<StatusBar>
    <StatusBarItem Visibility="{Binding ElementName=_StatusbarUser, Path=Visibility}">
        <WrapPanel>
            <Image Source="/MyApp;component/Images/icon.png" />
            <TextBlock Name="_StatusbarUser" Text="Username" />
        </WrapPanel>
    </StatusBarItem>
</StatusBar>
```