# Binding child element property to parent element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Button in which an image is embedded in it.Now what I want is to bind the tag property of the button to Source property of the image.

```
<Button Name="Jobs" Tag={Binding ???} Click="button_click">
  <Button.Content>
    <Image Source="{StaticResource nsds}"/>
   <Button.Content>
</Button>
```

I want it to be general since every button that will be created will have this Image content and the button creation will be done dynamically.
Binding with Image Name will defeat the purpose`Tag={Binding ElementName=Img, Path=Source}` as i have to use the source of the image to recreate the image elsewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Parent Property From Children in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599888/set-parent-property-from-children-in-wpf)

Comment: Is that something that a simple Style can't fix? Else, you'd bind Image's `Source` property to `{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}` or something like that

Comment: It seems you are trying to solve some problem by binding to `Tag` something.  Which one?

Comment: @Kilazur But then i can't access the tag value of button.I want to access the source value through tag value of button so that I can use it code behind so that changing the content presentation inside  the button  will not have any impact in code behind otherwise it will break .

Comment: @Sinator I want to display the same image elsewhere so I want to extract the image source whenever button is clicked.

Comment: @ankyAS got it, you want to bind `Image.Source` to `Button.Tag`. You can't do that dynamically due to how binding works; the only way I can think of is by using ElementName binding. It seems to me that you're making your problem way more complicated than it needs to be, and I can think of some stuff that could surely help you (converters for example). Can you clarify your final need?

Comment: @Kilazur that's not entirely true, Tag is just an arbitrary property you can pass whatever you want into, including the string of a source. However I'm little curious what the end result actually is since the example provided and the OP's last comment kind of negate what I thought he was trying to do originally. Sounds like something that maybe should be slapped in a Style template and be done with it.

Comment: @ankyAS, Why don't you reverse the `Binding`? That is, write the `Tag` property of the `Button` with the `StaticResource`, and then create a `Binding` for the `Source` property of the `Image`.

    `<Button Tag="{StaticResource nsds}">
        <Image Source="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}"/>
    </Button>`

I find more natural for the containing element to give the information to its children, and not viceversa. The viceversa often (not always, often) implies that the application design have some smell.

Comment: @Chris This is right, and I most likely poorly phrased my thought. What I meant is that, as far as I know, you can't bind a parent property to a child's one.

Answer (score 3):

In the example you've provided the easiest way to achieve your goal is to use binding with relative source in `Self` mode:

```
<Button Tag="{Binding Content.Source, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" (...)>
    <Button.Content>
        <Image Source="{StaticResource nsds}"/>
    <Button.Content>
</Button>
```

This works because the value of `Content` is the `Image`, hence `Content.Source` path relative to the `Button` itself points to the source of your image. This however will stop working if the `Image` control is not the actual content of your button (e.g. it is nested in a `Grid` etc.).

Given what you're after it may be more logical to set the image as the content of your button and use a template:

```
<Button Content="{StaticResource nsds}">
    <Button.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Button.ContentTemplate>
</Button>
```

This, I think, is more precise representation of your model - the logical content of the button is the actual image, and `Image` control is just a mean to display that image. This solution has one drawback though - the value of `Button.Content` property will not be automatically converted to an `ImageSource` object, but will contain the raw value, in your case the `nsds` object (possibly a `string` representing an URI, but you know better what it is).

### EDIT

If I understand your comment correctly you want to devise a way to minimize the code you'd need to write to define such a button - you suggested wrapping it up in a user control of some sort. That can be done, but usually in such scenario, where you want to throw a couple of property setters into one logical bag, it is better to use `Style` to do so.

In this case you can define the `Style` as a resource somewhere:

```
<Style x:Key="nsdsButton" TagetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource nsds}" />
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then whenever you want to define such button you simply need to write:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource nsdsButton}" />
```

Comment: can't i convert that into some user control so that same button can be used multiple times instead of specifically binding the image source to Button Content which is static here.I want it to template Binding and then use static resource when actually using the button instead binding in user control.